# Wrap few elements and their child elements in side a  tag . JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to wrap dynamically generated elements and their child elements inside a `<div>` or `<span>` tag  so that I can hide/show as per the requirement.

```
<tr>
  <td class="SubHeader1" colspan="3" rowspan="1">For those drivers:</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="TextBold" align="left" valign="middle">16.</td>
  <td class="TextBold" align="left" valign="middle">Text for Question 16:</td>
  <td class="TextBold" align="left" valign="middle">
   <input name="ctl00$DefaultContent$ctl15" type="text" class="TextNormal" style="width:36px;" />      
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="TextBold" align="left" valign="middle">17.</td>
   <td class="TextBold" align="left" valign="middle">Content for Question 17:</td>
   <td class="TextBold" align="left" valign="middle">
     <input name="ctl00$DefaultContent$ctl16" type="text" class="TextNormal" style="width:36px;" />
   </td>
</tr>
```

There are only two **class=SubHeader1** in the entire page and I want to wrap the **second** `<tr>` and `<td>` containing the "**SubHeader1**" and also the following two `<tr>`s.

Here is what I was able to come up with seems not working.

```
$('.SubHeader1:eq(1)').parent().each(function () {
            $(this).add($(this).next()).wrapAll('<div class="HideShow"></div>');
  })
```

Thank in advance

BB

Comment: Do you want to wrap a `<tr>` with a `<div>`? Is that valid HTML?

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson Apparently not: http://jsfiddle.net/J5dHn/ -- the DOM inspector in IE9 and Chrome report that those browsers don't just ignore the DIV, they actually remove it.

Comment: You can't wrap <td>s OR <tr>s in divs, you would no longer have a valid table. You can however wrap the contends of a <td> in a div. Are you trying to group to adjacent <tr>s?

Answer (score 1):

Since jamming `<div>`s inside the working bits of a `<table>` will invalidate your html and only cause heartache, how about we give the `<tr>`s themselves a class which you can then use for show/hiding

```
var $target = $('.SubHeader1:eq(1)');// we'll cache this for readability
$target.add( $target.next() ).add( $target.next().next() ).addClass('HideShow');
```